# How to compare two dictionary and extract other values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 1 dictionary and 1 csv

d1

```
"Name","module","code","Message","MessageForRole"
"Country","Request","11101","Data Approved","Country User"
"Country","Request","11102","Data Granted","Country User"
"Country","Request","11103","Data Denied","Country User"
"Country","Request","11201","Data Request","Data Owner"
```

```
d2 = { "Name" : "Country",
"module": "Request",
"code" : 11101}
```

My incoming dictionary is `d2`

From `d2` if the value of `d1` is same then

extract `code, MessageForRole, Message` from `d1` dictionary

My Expected output

`{'Name': 'Country','Message': 'Data Approved', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User' }`

My code is not working

```
    res = {}
    for conf in range(0, len(d1)):
        if int(d1["code"]) == int(d2['code']) and \
                d1["applicationName"] == d2['applicationName'] and \
                d1["moduleName"] == d2['moduleName']:
               res['Name'] = d1['Name']
               res['Message'] = d1['Message']
               res['MessageForRole'] = d1['MessageForRole']
```

Comment: You say you want to extract Code. Is it true? it seem you want "Name", as your expected output show. Clarify it please.

Comment: @sim, do you mean to match with the code of d2 with d1 and extract the respective matched dictionary containing the Name, Message and MessageRole?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat yes

Comment: @coldy exactly correctl

Comment: so your d1 what is it when you import the csv? A dataframe?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat not dataframe, please dont do in Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should do the trick. It initialises `d1` with the contents of the CSV file and `d2` with the keys and values to match (note I changed the code in `d2` to a string).

Then, for each dict `d` in `d1`, the keys and values from `d2` are compared with those of `d`. If all of the keys and values match a new dict is created from `d` with the required extraction keys.

```
import csv

EXTRACTION_KEYS = ('Name', 'Message', 'MessageForRole')

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    d1 = list(csv.DictReader(f))

d2 = { "Name" : "Country", "module": "Request", "code" : "11101"}    #N.B. code is now a string

for d in d1:
    if all(d.get(k) == v for k,v in d2.items()):
        print({k: d.get(k) for k in EXTRACTION_KEYS})
```

Assuming `input.csv` contains the data provided in your question the output will be:

```
{'Name': 'Country', 'Message': 'Data Approved', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User'}
```

If you want to collect all of the dicts that match `d2` into a list, this list comprehension should do it:

```
>>> [{k: d.get(k) for k in EXTRACTION_KEYS} for d in d1 if all(d.get(k) == v for k,v in d2.items())]
[{'Name': 'Country', 'Message': 'Data Approved', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

CSV (data.csv):

```
Name,module,code,Message,MessageForRole
Country,Request,11101,Data Approved,Country User
Country,Request,11102,Data Granted,Country User
Country,Request,11103,Data Denied,Country User
Country,Request,11201,Data Request,Data Owner
```

I think this is what you are trying to do:

1. To read the csv and create a dictionary of it (note that it can be achieved various ways).
2. Use this data_dictionary to perform matching

#### Creating the data dictionary from csv, idea to get the header and create the dictionary of it accordingly.

```
def create_data_dict(data_lines):
    data_dicts = list()
    for idx, line in enumerate(data_lines):
        if idx == 0:
            headers = line.split(",")
        else:
            data_line = line.split(",")
            temp_dict = {}
            for header, data_val in zip(headers, data_line):
                temp_dict[header] = data_val
            data_dicts.append(temp_dict)
    return data_dicts
```

#### Reading the file and performing the matching

```
f_reader = open("data.csv", "r")
d2 = {"Name": "Country", "module": "Request", "code": 11101}
data_lines = f_reader.readlines()
data_dicts = create_data_dict(data_lines)
f_reader.close()

for item in data_dicts:
    if int(d2["code"] == int(item["code"])):
        print("Message -- ", item["Message"])
        print("Name -- ", item["Name"])
        # Do something else
```

#### Output:

```
Message -- Data Approved
Name -- Country
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the data below:

```
d1 = [ { 'Name': 'Country', 'module': 'Request', 'code': '11101', 'Message': 'Data Approved', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User' }, { 'Name': 'Country', 'module': 'Request', 'code': '11102', 'Message': 'Data Granted', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User' }, { 'Name': 'Country', 'module': 'Request', 'code': '11103', 'Message': 'Data Denied', 'MessageForRole': 'Country User' }, { 'Name': 'Country', 'module': 'Request', 'code': '11201', 'Message': 'Data Request', 'MessageForRole': 'Data Owner' } ]

d2 = { "Name" : "Country", "module": "Request", "code" : 11101}
```

I have create the next code. First I define one auxiliary function names check:

```
#What this function does is check if one dictionary has the same values of d2. Take in consideration that d1 must be a single dictionary, not a list of  dictionary as you have defined.

def check(d1, d2):
    for e in d2:
        if type(d2[e])==int:
            if d2[e]!=int(d1[e]):
                return False
            
        else:
            if d2[e]!=d1[e]:
                return False
            
    return True
```

Once we have this function defined, let's iterate for all the dictionary you have inside d1. For do that, and return the new dictionary, I create the next function:

```
output_keys=["Name", "MessageForRole", "Message" ] # We also define which output values we want

def new_dict(d1,d2):
    doutput={}
    for d in d1:     
        if check(d,d2)==True: #Here we use the function defined before to check if both dictionary have the same values
            for e in output_keys:
                doutput[e]=d[e]
        
            return(doutput)
```

So if we call the final function with your d1 and d2 defined we obtain the next output:

```
new_dict(d1,d2)

{'Name': 'Country',
 'MessageForRole': 'Country User',
 'Message': 'Data Approved'}
```

This program will always return **the values of the first dictionary of d1** that fits the condition.